# ABCpdf cannot find office installed

Tags: abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf.net in a web-application.
when i try to convert regular images everything works well.
but when i try to convert an ms-office file (docx, ppt etc..) i get the following error.

> Neither OpenOffice.org, Microsoft Office nor WordGlue is installed.

I have office 2013 installed, and i have already set the Administraotr account to run the ApplicationPool to rule the permissions out...

and still i get this error message.

any help ? suggestions ?

Comment: What web app? What's a "regal" image?

Comment: @DonLarynx an asp.net web application written in mvc.net and regal = regular image e.g. png, jpg etc...

Answer (score 0):

Using the lastest ABCpdf 9.1.2.5 will fix the issue.

I encounter same issue using ABCpdf 9.1.1.3